# JQuery Mobile Scrolling not smooth on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, smooth-scrolling

I have a multi-page app written with JQuery 1.4, displayed in an iOS WebView.  It uses a static header and the content has 20 or so divs with embedded images and text.  I am not using PhoneGap.

In the WebView *and* in Safari, I can scroll through the content vertically, but I don't get the same smoothness you'd get in an iOS app (i.e. the scroll continues for a bit after finger comes up = "smooth" scrolling).  The scroll just stops when my finger comes off the screen.

Is there a setting or issue I don't know about when it comes to smooth scrolling of content in JQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 21):

I think it has to do with the fact that you are no longer scrolling the `<body>` element, but rather a JQuery Mobile Page `<div>`.  If you make a `<div>` scrollable without JQuery Mobile, you should be able to replicate this choppy experience.

What you are looking for is actually called **momentum scrolling** and is sometimes also referred to as **inertial scrolling**.

Supposedly, you should be able to add the css property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the div you want to add momentum scrolling to and it should work, but I have not been able to get this to work on the Page `<div>`. I did try adding it to the body and I was able to get the right scrolling, but my fixed header started jumping around while I was scrolling.

If you don't have a fixed header, feel free to give it a shot.

```
body {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;    
}
```

Comment: So in my case, I had someone else working on the app and they put in a bad CSS rule which caused this bad experience.  I discovered this by stripping out all the CSS except the JQuery Mobile CSS.  Then I slowly added the rest of the custom CSS until I located the bad rule.  It was pretty frustrating, but was a consequence of multiple people working on the same project.  The reason why I thought it was JQuery Mobile at first was because I had also tried removing JQuery Mobile and the app worked fine without it.  So I guess the 2 rules were competing.

Comment: Champion! This helped alot.

Comment: For me it helped too. Thank-you Scott! Can you tell us additionally, what you identified as "bad rules" in your project?

Comment: yeah, he added this to the css which served no purpose: `html { 
overflow-y: scroll; }`   After I deleted it, problem solved.

Comment: this is what worked for me.
`.wrapper { -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow-y: scroll; }`

Comment: @ScottDavidMurphy Have you fixed the issue WITH a fixed header?

Answer (score 4):

For us, the problem was in the CSS of jQuery Mobile, and we fixed it like this:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page-active{display:block;overflow:visible;/*overflow-x:hidden*/}
```

Fixed the scrolling error for us.

`overflow-x: hidden` messed things up.

Comment: Everybody having that problem, try this one first!

Comment: Have the same problem but the provided solution does not work. As soon as I have to set a height to the scrollable DIV the scrolling doesn't work anymore (jitters).

Comment: Thanks for this in 2020! It fixed my vertical scrolling problem, although I had to add overflow-x:unset;

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is that it is taking lots of processing power to paint those images/divs. Did you compress your files?

You can read here for more:

Image Compression
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/img-compression/
**scroll to bottom for links to apps you can use

CSS Paint Times Cause Problems
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/css-paint-times/
**make sure to click the link "Continuous Paint Times" at the bottom to see how to profile paint times.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, and perhaps that is the problem but scrolling actually works just fine as long as my finger is down - no jitter or anything.

The problem is after a swipe - the scrolling just stops and doesn't follow the momentum of the swipe (like it does for most native scroll views).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Dave Taylor's jquery kinetic library to add some scrolling activity to containers:
http://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use nicescroll plugin that works on many platforms.

**Installation:**

```
<script src="jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
```

**Usage:**

```
$(document).ready(

  function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll();

  }

);
```

Here is the reference for [nicescroll plugin](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/)